# Java Error while reading pdf with Python using Tabula

Tags: java, python-3.x, dataframe, pdf, tabula

I have installed the tabula library for reading pdf into a pandas dataframe using python.
But when I run the code

```
import tabula
df=tabula.read_pdf("sample1.pdf",pages='1')
```

I get the Exception.

```
SEVERE: Cannot read JPEG2000 image: Java Advanced Imaging (JAI) Image I/O Tools are not installed
```

Solutions I have tried:

1. Re-installing the Java JDK  and ensuring it is added to path(verified with java-version)
2. Installed the Java Advanced Imaging tools from this [link](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/java-archive-downloads-java-client-downloads.html) and restarting my system
3. Uninstalling and installing tabula with `pip install tabula-py`

Please let me know if I overlooked something.